# Eloquent create column if not in whereIn()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a query like this:

```
$valid_statuses = array('1', '2', '3');

$results = User::with(['posts' => function($query) use ($valid_statuses) {
            $query->whereIn('status', $valid_statuses);
        }
    ])
    ->get();
```

An example of the table looks like this:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | post_id | status |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |       1 |      2 |
|  3 |       2 |      1 |
|  4 |       2 |      3 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

What I need the query to do is, if a `post_id` is missing a `valid_status`, it needs to add the missing status to the query result. The output resultant query should look like:

```
+----+---------+--------+
| id | post_id | status |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |       1 |      2 |
|  3 |       1 |      3 |
|  4 |       2 |      1 |
|  5 |       2 |      2 |
|  6 |       2 |      3 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to update all posts for a specific user to have all 3 of those statuses and you don't know which have already been created?

Comment: No, I want to select all posts, but fill in the missing statuses if that status doesn't exist for that particular `post_id`. i.e. if `post_id` has statuses 1 and 2, but not 3, have the query add 3 to the results.

Comment: What is the name of the table with post_id and status? Does it have it's own model? Is it set up as a belongsTo relationship in the Post model?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a many-to-many relationship between a Post and Status model, you could do something like this.

Maintain the original database records:

```
foreach($valid_statuses as $status_id) {
    $have_status = Post::whereHas('status_id', $status_id)->lists('id');
    $need_status = Post::whereNotIn('id', $valid_posts)->lists('id');
    Status::find($status_id)->posts()->sync($need_status, false);
}
```

Or if you don't care about the original records:

```
foreach($valid_statuses as $status_id) {
    Status::find($status_id)->posts()->sync(Post::all()->lists('id'));
}
```